# Count multiple occurrences in a set list

Tags: python, list, count

Is there a way to count the amount occurrences of a set of string lists?

For example, when I have this list, it counts 7 `' '` blanks.

```
list = [[' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ']]
print(list.count(' '))
```

Is there a way I can do this same thing but for a set of multiple lists? Like this for example below:

```
set = [[' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' '], 
       [' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' '], 
       [' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ']]
print(set.count(' '))
```

When I do it this same way, the output I get is `0` and not the actual count of occurrences.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Solution

This works:

```
>>> data = [[' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' '], 
            [' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' '], 
            [' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ']]
>>> sum(x.count(' ') for x in data)
21
```

You need to count in each sub list. I use a [generator expression](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#generator-expressions) to do this and sum the results from all sub lists.
BTW, don't use `set` as a variable name. It is a built-in.

## Performance

While not that important for many cases, performance can be interesting:

```
%timeit sum(x.count(' ') for x in data)
1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.28 µs per loop
```

vs.

```
%timeit sum(1 for i in chain.from_iterable(data) if i==' ')
100000 loops, best of 3: 4.79 µs per loop
```